# Informatica Powercenter - Load contents of XML file to CLOB column

Tags: xml, file-handling, informatica, informatica-powercenter, clob

Is it possible to pick up an XML file via Powercenter and load the entirety of it into a target table's CLOB column? I have some code which is currently doing this completely in Oracle, but would like to perform the same process in Powercenter.

Or is the only option to call an procedure from within Powercenter to perform this insert?

Answer (score 1):

of course its possible.

1. Set the DB target field as clob if not done already.
2. Set the FILE source field as text with length like 100000. Pls note there can be some issues if its too large. Need to test it out.
3. All transformations should use string/text data type with length as 100000.

Pls note, there can be some perf problem if you are trying to do some transformations to this field.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I did try this method, but the xml doesn't seem to parse correctly. It stops at the end of the first line itself. I have defined the source flat file as delimited with row delimiter \020 DLE.

Comment: ok then, you can use an aggregator to concat all lines into 1 line. kind of like `listagg()` in oracle.

Comment: Note - I did get it to work eventually. Changed the source definition to fixed width. But the main change was to use an update override so that I could specify to use the XMLTYPE function in the insert statement. A simple insert will never work.

Comment: very nice, check out the perf as well when you insert data

Comment: @dreadnought303: consider posting the solution details for any future developers facing same issue. Or for yourself if you happen to face it again after forgetting the details ;)